# Python Transposing a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How transpose my matrix in python

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

into:

```
B = [[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4]]??
```

A is numpy.array.
When I transpose it by using A = A.T i get:

```
B = [[1,
      2,
      3,
      4]]
```

Thanks for help!

It must be exactly like:

```
B = [[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4]]
```

Not:

```
B = [[[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4]]]
```

Not:

```
 B = [[1]\n\n,[2]\n\n,[3]\n\n,[4]\n\n]
```

Look into debugger, not what is printed.
U know what I mean?

Comment: Your `A` as displayed is a list, not numpy array.  But if made into a list, its shape will be (4,) (1d).  What you want has a shape of (4,1).  You can either reshape that directly, or you can make a (1,4) shape array, and transpose that.  This is not MATLAB where everything is 2d to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new axis:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
A = A[:, np.newaxis]
print(A)
```

**Output**

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
```